# Meaning of "nonsensical"

Tags: word-meaning

If someone is talking about something that doesn't exist, can I say it's nonsensical?

For example, is "unicorns have horns on  their heads" nonsensical because unicorns don't exist?

Likewise is "three which is one plus one is a number" nonsensical because three which is one plus one doesn't exist?

Comment: Not everything that doesn't exist is nonsensical.

Comment: Note, "nonsensical" has stronger implications than "nonsense." You can use "nonsense" just to dismiss a frivolous subject: "Unicorns have horns on their head." "Quit talking nonsense and stick to reality!" But "nonsensical" means it doesn't actually make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of different types of nonsense.

Things can be nonsense because they use made up words:

> The humpalumf glomped over the baawey.

Or because it is ridiculously untrue.

> The sun is a balloon.  It goes pop every night.

> Three is one plus one.

Or we can call something nonsense because it is a very bad idea.

> We should make all children go out to work from age 13.

Or because the order of the words doesn't make any meaning at all

> Literature verse strong employing a nonsense of prosodic usually is elements form nonsense.

But **fantasy** isn't the same as nonsense.  The following is fantasy, not nonsense;

> In a hole in the ground lived a hobbit.

And talking about unicorns is fantasy.  It makes sense, in the context of your imagination.

> Unicorns have a horn on their heads.

Comment: We can also use 'nonsensical' about an idea, plan, proposal, etc, that we think is a bad idea e.g. because it is bound to fail or will lead to a very bad result.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey adopted.